# What are the properties of matrix inversion using the Cholesky decomposition for non symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I managed to find some information on the [properties of matrix inversion](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn27.pdf) using the LU decomposition. There is also some material on doing the inversion using the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Matrix_inversion) for non-symmetric matrices.

I haven't been able to find any information on how Cholesky decomposition inversion behaves in practice. Would it be on par with the LU decomposition inversion in terms of speed and stability?

Comment: "Properties" is an extremely broad term. It sounds like you are asking specifically about numerical stability? If so it would be good to edit your question title to be more specific.

Comment: I am asking about numerical stability and performance, though it is not like I am like averse to knowing more. I think the title is good enough as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inverting a nonsymmetric matrix $A$ by $A^{-1}=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$ using the Cholesky factorization of $AA^T$ is a pretty bad idea both in terms of complexity and numerical stability.

There is absolutely nothing saved in terms of the number of operations. Forming the product $AA^T$ prior to its factorization involves about $n^3$ flops (yes, yes, Strassen gives a better exponent). With the cost of $n^3/3$ flops of the Cholesky factorization this gives $4n^3/3$ flops in total. This is twice more expensive than LU and just same as the Householder QR factorization for $A$ directly.

Not only this approach of inversion is not faster in any way, it is also inferior to almost any other method one might think of. The numerical errors committed by solving systems like $AA^T$ are proportional to the square of the condition number of $A$ which in turn roughly halves the number of valid digits in the solution compared to more stable methods based on LU or QR.

Comment: Thank you, this is the kind of reply I've been hoping for. All it is missing is a reference or two. Having said that, I am not entirely sure though how to reason about numerical errors in this context. I can sense that squaring the matrix A, decomposing it, inverting it, squaring its inverse factor and multiplying it by the transpose of the original matrix will give a lot of numerical errors and it seems plausible that it would be worse that LU decomposition. How would one prove that the inverse using LU decomposition is better than using the Cholesky?

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic Some more details can be found in classic books on the subject, e.g., [this one](https://books.google.be/books?isbn=0898718023). A nice explanation on why "squaring" the matrix is bad can be found [here](https://books.google.be/books?isbn=0898713609).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a Cholesky decomposition for non symmetric matrices.

As the decomposition has the form

$$A=LL^T$$ you obviously must have

$$A^T=A.$$

Comment: I am aware of this. What I am talking about is using the Cholesky decomposition as a part of a matrix inversion method.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to compute the inverse of a triangular matrix and there exist numerical solutions. Then the original matrix inverse is computed simply by multiplying the two inverses as
$$
A^{-1} = \left(L^{-1}\right)^T L^{-1}
$$
for $L$ being lower-triangular from Cholesky decomposition $A = LL^T.$

**EDIT:** For more optimized version see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.4144.pdf).

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question. I am not even talking about the symmetric matrix inverse.